# How can I find the values of $x$ where a function lies below or above the axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's imagine this problem:

> Find the values of $x$ where the graph of $$f(x)= \frac{3x^2}{x^2-1}$$ lies below the $x$-axis.

I know how to find the intercept $(0,0)$, but I don't understand what it means to be “below the axis” that’s $\,f(-1)$?

Comment: "below the axis" means $f(x)<0$.  Also, $f(-1)$ is undefined, as you cannot divide by zero.

Comment: How can I check the values that lies below a second graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below that axis means that $f(x) <0$ so

$$\frac{3x^{2}}{x^{2}-1} <0 \iff  \frac{3x^{2}}{(x-1)(x+1)}< 0  $$

From here yo have to find the intervals that make $f(x) <0 $

Comment: Something like (x-1)(x+1)<0 
                  Where -1>0 ?

Comment: $-1>0$ ?????  $(x-1)(x+1) < 0 \iff x \in ]-1,1[$  so thats the solution!! the interval $]-1,1[$ is where the graph lies below th $x $ axis

Comment: Do you know how can I check the values that lies below an specific value of $f(X)$ ?

Comment: If you take a value of $x \in ]-1,1[ - \{0\}$ and you change it in the function, you will see that it will be always negative.

Comment: or in other words below the $x$ axis

Comment: This is what I'm asking for >> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949954/value-of-x-where-the-graph-lies-below-the-graph-of-fx