# Value of $x$ where the graph lies below the graph of f(X)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From this question ([How can I find the values of $x$ where a function lies below or above the axis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949872/how-can-i-find-the-values-of-x-where-a-function-lies-below-or-above-the-axis/949884#949884)) I learn that "lies below" means $f(x)<0$ , now my question is , how can I check values that lie below a graph and a value of $f(X).$

For example :

Find the values of $x$ where the graph of $f(X)=|2x+3|$ lies below the graph of $f(x)=4$

My guess is that if "lies below" means $f(x)<0$ , then below $f(x)=4$ would be any value that is bigger than the expression.

$f(4)=|2x+3|<11$

Comment: lies below doesn't means $x<0$, the graph lies below the $x$ axis if $f(x) <0$ which is different.

Comment: Fixed , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

What you have to find are the values of $x$ that make

$$|2x+3|<4$$

[image]

Comment: $f(X)=4$ does not mean to replace 4 in the first expression?

Comment: $1/2 , -7/2$ right?

Comment: $f(x) = 4$ is another function

Comment: yes, $\frac{-7}{2}<x< \frac{1}{2}$ those are the $x´s$ of the graph of $f(x) = |2x+3|$ that lie below the graph $f(x) = 4$

Comment: You're welcome ;)